# How to correctly use assertRaises in Django

Tags: django, python-unittest, django-testing, django-tests, django-errors

I have the following validation function in my model:

```
@classmethod
def validate_kind(cls, kind):
    if kind == 'test':
        raise ValidationError("Invalid question kind")
```

which I am trying to test as follows:

```
w = Model.objects.get(id=1) 

self.assertRaises(ValidationError, w.validate_kind('test'),msg='Invalid question kind')
```

I also tried:

```
self.assertRaisesRegex(w.validate_kind('test'),'Invalid question kind')
```

Both of these don't work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The way you are calling `assertRaises` is wrong - you need to [pass a callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) instead of calling the function itself, and pass any arguments to the function as arguments to `assertRaises`. Change it to:

```
self.assertRaises(ValidationError, w.validate_kind, 'test')
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer isn't correct. `self.assertRaises()` doesn't check the exception message.

#### Correct answer

If you want to assert the exception message, you should use [self.assertRaisesRegex()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex).

```py
self.assertRaisesRegex(ValidationError, 'Invalid question kind', w.validate_kind, 'test')
```

or

```py
with self.assertRaisesRegex(ValidationError, 'Invalid question kind'):
    w.validate_kind('test')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError, msg='Invalid question kind'):
    w.validate_kind('test')
```

This may well be a change in Python since the question was originally asked.